# How to have NInject follow type hierarchy?

Tags: c#, ninject

I am surprised that NInject does not follow the type hierarchy when looking for a binding.

```
Bind<ICollection<ICard>>().ToConstructor(/* .. */);
var Cards = IoC.Kernel.Get<IList<ICard>>();
```

In the above code, the `Kernel.Get<..>()` sends me an `ActivationException` because I haven't explicitely bound `IList<ICard>`. In other words, for NInject, an `IList<ICard>` is not an `ICollection<ICard>`. Sounds strange to me.

Of course I can remove the error by explicitely adding `Bind<IList<ICard>>().To<..>()`, but I don't understand why NInject doesn't follow type hierarchy by default. Am I missing something?

So, can somebody explain:

- Why NInject forces me to be that specific in my bindings
- How I can overcome this behaviour without adding a tedious list of bindings for every possible collection (unless you convince me that it is a very bad practice to do so)